# PHPUnit 3.5 keeps showing errors

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I am trying to get phpunit 3.5 working. But everytime i run my tests i get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestFailure' not found in C:\wamp\bin
\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php on line 266
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\phpunit:49
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Tex
tUI\Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUni
t\TextUI\Command.php:188
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUni
t\TextUI\TestRunner.php:305
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUni
t\Framework\TestSuite.php:693
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PH
PUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:733
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit
\Framework\TestSuite.php:757
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUn
it\Framework\TestCase.php:576
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->addError() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\
PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:717

Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestFailure' not found in C:\wamp\bin\php\
php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php on line 266

Call Stack:
    0.0004     327336   1. {main}() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\phpunit:0
    0.3024     699040   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3
.9\phpunit:49
    0.3024     699392   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.
9\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
    0.3929    3300128   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\wamp\bin\php\ph
p5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:188
    0.4153    3766872   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\ph
p5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:305
    0.4154    3767136   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\ph
p5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:693
    0.4155    3767336   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() C:\wamp\bin\ph
p\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:733
    0.4155    3767336   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\php
5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:757
    0.4158    3767336   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() C:\wamp\bin\php\p
hp5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:576
    0.4257    3934600  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->addError() C:\wamp\bin\
php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:717


c:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\page\test>
```

And this is my include path:

```
string(252) "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php;C:\wamp\www\Zend
SkeletonApplication\module\page/test;C:\wamp\www\ZendSkeletonApplication\vendor\
ZendFramework\library;.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear;C:\pear\pear;C:\pear\pear;
C:\pear\pear;C:\pear\pear"
```

The file TestFailure doe exist.

So any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the full `PHPUNit` directory in your path and you also must manually include the autoloader. So at the top of your php file, add this:

```
require 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php'
```

And in your include path, change the PHPUnit part to just `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit` (instead of what you currently have, `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php`).

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it manually, seems like this old version is buggy

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestFailure.php';
```